# Keras LSTM on sequence of vectors

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to learn recurrent networks with keras using a toy example. The dataset is defined as follows:

```
pos = [1,2,3,4] # positive observation.
neg = [1,2,3,0] # negative observation.
half_len = 500

data = np.reshape(np.concatenate((np.tile(pos, half_len), np.tile(neg, half_len)), axis=0), (2 * half_len, -1))
labels = np.asarray([1] * half_len + [0] * half_len)
```

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim=16))
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

As expected, this easily reaches accuracy 1. But the Embedding layer does not fit my real use case. When I reformat the toy example to the following:

```
pos = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
neg = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
half_len = 500

time_steps = 4
feature_length = 5

data = np.reshape(np.concatenate((np.tile(pos, half_len), np.tile(neg, half_len)), axis=0), (2 * half_len, time_steps, feature_length))
labels = np.asarray([1] * half_len + [0] * half_len)
```

And the model to:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_shape=(time_steps, feature_length)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The accuracy varies around 0.6 (I let it train 5 times longer than the first version). How are the 2 above not equivalent? What would be  a good way to adapt the model to the second input?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' you are creating is wrong. In your 'data', full array (i.e. [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])  is not repeatedly added rather you are adding same element (i.e [1,0,0,0,0]) for multiple time which is considered as a single input.

```
d1 = np.asarray(np.split(np.tile(pos,(500,1)),500))
d2 = np.asarray(np.split(np.tile(neg,(500,1)),500))
data= np.append(d1,d2,axis=0)
```

Use this as data and you will get accuracy 1.